# excel corrupt on laravel 5.4

Tags: excel, laravel

i upgraded my project from 5.1 to 5.4 and now whenver i try to export data i got a corrupt xls file, even though i am using the same code as laravel 5.1, when i try to open the file i get this error

> the file format and extension of 'client.xls' don't match. the file could be corrupted or unsafe, Unless you trust its source , don't open it

I read that i should check for whitespaces and anomalies in the code, but it's the same code no spaces.
i am using `Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel` 
[image]
Thank you

Comment: I would, as you are the source, open the file and see if it is what you expect. If it is then you don't have a problem - the system is warning you about a possible error. If it is not what you expect then you have to find out what is going on. Another possibility is to go back to 5.1 and check all is still ok.

Comment: everything works perfectly on 5.1, i don't understand what's the big difference between 5.1 and 5.4 when it comes to laravel-excel

Answer (score 0):

I also use that library - it's a standard windows error thrown with user-created Excel files (at least in my experience).

I've never had a problem just continuing to open it.

Comment: Thank you but when i open the file a git deformed data and characters

Comment: You will have to post up some code then - post the excel creation code; there is something in there that has changed or something else going on (perhaps an older version of the library is installed than the latest one that is compatible with 5.4?)

Comment: Have you called a different character set by default in 5.4?

Comment: i don't understand